# I have a project of ruby on rails downloaded from net...how to execute that project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a project of ruby on rails downloaded from net...how to execute that project?

if possible **send me the links** or include the steps

I have **Eclipse as an IDE** and concerned plug in installed!

Comment: Please go through some tutorials on how to get up and running with Ruby on Rails. First install Ruby and Ruby Gems. The best place to start with rails is: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html Then follow the steps provided by the answers below. A simple Google Search of `ruby on rails install` will solve your problems. Was that so hard to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the `script/server` that's inside the project directory (you can use the terminal provided on your system).
Then, according to the convention, and provided Ruby on Rails is properly installed, you should be able to access your site via http://localhost:3000.

Comment: thanks!! but understood a little , but how todo that ??
can u describe in steps

Comment: @javatechi, you really don't know how to *run a program*????

Comment: @pavel shved yeah !! earlier was doing java programming...for Ruby this is my first day !!

Comment: It depends on which platform you're running.

Answer (score 2):

I think , this is where you should start :
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using Heroku. It will let you host your Rails project quickly on the web.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up your terminal or command prompt
2. cd to the project directory
3. Type: "ruby script/server"
4. Open your browser
5. Go to http://localhost:3000